# What type to use in tests which require Concurrent and Timer type class instance?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

Consider the following example:

```
import cats.Functor
import cats.effect.{Concurrent, Timer}
import cats.syntax.functor._
import fs2.Stream

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class FetchAndSum[F[_]: Timer: Concurrent: Functor](fetch: List[String] => F[List[Int]]) {

  def run(inputs: List[String]): F[Int] =
    Stream
      .emits(inputs)
      .covary[F]
      .groupWithin(20, 10.millis)
      .mapAsync(10)(chunk => fetch(chunk.toList))
      .flatMap(Stream.emits)
      .reduce(_ + _)
      .compile
      .last
      .map(_.getOrElse(0))
}
```

In production this is instantiated with the `IO` Monad.

In my tests I would like to test **how many times the `fetch` function gets called**. If `F[_]` would require only a `Functor` instance, I could do that simply with the `Writer` monad.

Due to the `mapAsync` and `groupedWithin` of fs2, `F[_]` must also have instances of `Timer` and `Concurrent`, those of course do not exist on `Writer`.

What data type could I use to test this in a functional way?

I thought about somehow combining an `IO` with a `Writer` e.g. `type IOWriter[A] = IO[Writer[Int, A]]`, but I was not able to make that work without redeclaring all the type class instances for `IOWriter`.

Is there something which allows me to achieve that without having to redeclare all the type class instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IO` with `Ref`:

```
val numsExecuted: IO[Int] = for {
  ref <- Ref[IO].of(0)
  fetch = (l: List[String]) => ref.update(_ + 1).as(???)
  _ <- new FetchAndSum[IO](fetch).run(???)
  x <- ref.get
} yield x
```

You can also use `Writer` combined with `IO`. This construct is known as Writer monad transformer (`type IOWriter[A] = cats.data.WriterT[IO, A]`) and should have Concurrent / Timer / Monad / etc. instances out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, Ref works perfectly and is super simple!! The solution with `WriterT[IO, ?]` does also compile, so the type class instances do exist, unfortunately it seems like fs2 mapAsync is not calling flatMap, since the `writtten` part is always empty. But the `Ref` solution is a lot better anyways.